# Is it possible to generate a TOC tree from my PHP domain?

Tags: php, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, documentation-generation, toctree

So I am writing a PHP documentation for my library.
I am using the "sphinxcontrib.phpdomain" extension in order to support the PHP domain.

Let's say I have defined the following document:

```
.. toctree::
    :numbered:
    :maxdepth: 3
    :caption: Couch

.. php:class:: Couch

    This is the low-level class that handles communications with CouchDB.

    .. php:method:: dsn()

        :returns: The dsn of the current Couch instance
```

Is it possible to generate a TOC tree from this? For example, I would like to index in the tree the class names and the classes members.

For the moment, only custom titles are indexed in the toctree

Answer (score 0):

Split your reStructuredText example into two files.  The `toctree` directive should be in the `index.rst` file of your documentation, and the `php:class` directive should be in a separate file. It would be wise to name such a file according to the name of the class, e.g., `couch.rst`. That will at least give you the top level TOC.

I don't know whether `sphinxcontrib.phpdomain` supports TOC entries other than simple reStructuredText file names and headings within the files.  Assuming `sphinxcontrib.phpdomain` does not provide the TOC depth you desire, you can try inserting arbitrary headings.

In Python, we have [`autodoc`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html) which automatically documents Python code, but I have no clue whether it works with PHP code. Otherwise there may be some package for PHP as `autodoc` is for Python.

Comment: The only PHP autodoc package that I found was outdated. For this reason, I decided to write the documentation manually. I found a temporary way of indexing my class and methods. I made a custom directly that define hidden headers. Those headers are hidden in the page but they are shows in the toc tree.